# How can I use one "if" to do the same job?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, return-value

I hope you all are well.

I have the method `subscriber`:

```
subscriber: function() {

    var self = this;

    self.hideError();
    self.sb.subscribe('seleccionProyecto_seleccionarTarea', function(data) {
        console.info(data);
        console.info(data.datos);
        // HERE I NEED TO RESUME THE CODE
        self.showModal();
        self.idPanel=data.iCont;
    });
},
```

I have the method `llenarTareasTemp`:

```
llenarTareasTemp: function(data){

    var self = this;
    $("#opt1").html("");
    var bEncontrado=false; // REPLACED BY RETURN FALSE.

    $.each(data.datos, function(index,value) {
        if(value!=undefined){ 
            for(var iCont=0;iCont<value.length;iCont++){
                if(self.objTareasTemp.idProyecto==value[iCont].idProyecto){
                    console.info(self.objTareasTemp.idProyecto,"=",value[iCont].idProyecto)
                    $("#opt1").append("<option>"+value[iCont].nombreTarea+"</option>"); 
                    $("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").selectpicker('refresh');
                    bEncontrado=true; // REPLACED BY RETURN TRUE.
                }
            }   
        }
    });
        //if(bEncontrado){
        //  self.conRegistro();
        //}else{
        //  self.sinRegistro();
        //  self.llenarTareasRegistradas(self.aDataServer);
        //}
},
```

And I have the method `llenarTareasRegistradas`:

```
llenarTareasRegistradas: function(data){

    var self = this;    

    $("#opt2").html(""); 
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].nombre_tarea != null){
                var cTareas = "<option value="+i+">"+data[i].nombre_tarea+"</option>"; 
                $("#opt2").append(cTareas); 
                $("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").selectpicker('refresh');  
                var bEncontrado=true; // REPLACED BY RETURN TRUE.
            }else{
                $("#opt2").append(""); 
                $("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").selectpicker('refresh');
                bEncontrado=false;  // REPLACED BY RETURN FALSE.
            }
        }      
        // if(bEncontrado){
        //self.conRegistro();
        //}else{
        //  self.sinRegistro();
        //} 
},
```

These codes work well , but I have to summarize this:

```
    if(bEncontrado){
            self.conRegistro();
        }else{
            self.sinRegistro();
        }
```

And this:

```
if(bEncontrado){
            self.conRegistro();
        }else{
            self.sinRegistro();
            self.llenarTareasRegistradas(self.aDataServer);
        }
```

IN ONE IF, in the method `subscriber`, between `console.info(data.datos);` and `self.showModal();`.

```
`self.conRegistro();` and `self.sinRegistro();` they are methods that call messages only.
```

To do what I want, I think that I have to replace some things.(I commented that things)

SO in the method `subscriber` , between `console.info(data.datos);` and `self.showModal();`, I dont know how order the two `if(bEncontrado)` (from `llenarTareasRegistradas` and `llenarTareasTemp`) using only ONE if , because i have to delete the two if in the methods.

A reference image.

In Part B , at the subscriber method , I have a little scheme that does nothing.

http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14321765021.jpg (you can zoom)

Please sorry my english and thank you.

**SOLUTION:**

I replace this code:

```
   if(bEncontrado){
   self.conRegistro();
   }else{
   self.sinRegistro();
```

by :  `return bEncontrado;`In the  method `llenarTareasTemp` and in the method `llenarTareasRegistradas`

And in the method `subscriber`, between `console.info(data.datos);` and `self.showModal();` I put:

```
        var temp = Boolean(self.llenarTareasTemp(data));
        var server = Boolean(self.llenarTareasRegistradas(self.aDataServer));

        if (temp || server) {
            self.conRegistro();
        }else{
            self.sinRegistro();         
         }
```

And work the same way, but with one "if" , thanks you all anyway and sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: There's no `bEncontrado` variable in the `subscriber` method. That's a local variable in the other two methods.

Comment: Do you want `subscriber` to call the other methods and use their values in its `if`?

Answer (score 1):

You should define one function "isEncontrado" like this:

```js
/** 
 * if encontrado call self.conRegistro() else call self.sinRegistro()
 * @param b is Encontrado
 * @param isNeedCall is need call self.llenarTareasRegistradas()
 */
isEncontrado : function(b, isNeedCall) {
    if (b) {
        self.conRegistro();
    } else {
        self.sinRegistro();
        if (isNeedCall) 
           self.llenarTareasRegistradas(self.aDataServer);
    }
}
```

Then call this function. example:

```js
llenarTareasTemp: function(data){

    var self = this;
    $("#opt1").html("");
    isEncontrado(false); // call function isEncontrado 
    $.each(data.datos, function(index,value) {
        if(value!=undefined){ 
            for(var iCont=0;iCont<value.length;iCont++){
                if(self.objTareasTemp.idProyecto==value[iCont].idProyecto){
                    console.info(self.objTareasTemp.idProyecto,"=",value[iCont].idProyecto)
                    $("#opt1").append("<option>"+value[iCont].nombreTarea+"</option>"); 
                    $("#select_seleccionar_proyecto_id").selectpicker('refresh');
                    isEncontrado(true, true); //call function isEncontrado
                }
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

I think you know what to do. Sorry my english is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but maybe this is what you want:

```
subscriber: function() {

    var self = this;

    self.hideError();
    self.sb.subscribe('seleccionProyecto_seleccionarTarea', function(data) {
        console.info(data);
        console.info(data.datos);
        if (self.llenarTareasTemp(data)) {
            self.conRegistro();
        } else {
            self.sinRegistro();
            self.llenarTareasRegistradas(self.aDataServer);
        }
        self.showModal();
        self.idPanel=data.iCont;
    });
},
```

Comment: not working fully, I need delete the "if" "bEncontrado" from the two methods and create one "if" in subscriber.  i need replace var bEncontrado=true; by return true and bEncontrado=flase by return false in both methods. i need something like a boolean i dont know. I need call when its true or false, in the same way as before, but with one if.. sorry if im not clear.. I'm a little desperate

Comment: No, it's still not clear at all. Instead of explaining what you want to with the `if` statements, explain what these functions are doing, and what problem you're trying to solve.